# Why should not a table size that's a power of 2 be used with the division hashing method?

Tags: hash

I have seen many people use the following to answer this problem.
"This is equivalent to just keeping the lower N bits of the hash while throwing away the upper bits".

But I do not quite understand what it means. could somebody explain and make an example?

Comment: If X is an integer then X mod 2\**n is simply the low-order n bits of X. What part don't you understand?

Comment: I got it, thank you